# Return a map and store the result in diferent variables

Tags: arrays, function, go, return

In JavaScript I can store the values of array into variables like this:

```
[a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

I created a variable function( it return a map with the same number of arguments), I would like to know if Go has a shortcut like JavaScript

Comment: you will need to do `a, b, c := arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the suggestion from comments ,I created a small example for your scenario:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

    func main() {
    
        myArray := []int{1, 2, 3}
        fmt.Println(myArray)
    
        a, b, c := myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2]
    
        fmt.Println(a, b, c)
    }
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
1 2 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax is not available in Go, however Go's syntax is sometimes concise too, depending what your input looks like.

Declaring and initializing several variables in a single LOC is straightforward, and it works even with variables of different types:

```
a, b, c := 42, "hello", 5.0
```

[Source](https://programming-idioms.org/idiom/249/declare-and-assign-multiple-variables/4414/go). [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EPIlKiwRm5p).

You can assign values to existing variables as well:

```
a, b, c = 42, "hello", 5.0
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_82aMt7TTJZ).

If your input data is a slice `s`, then per @Gopher's answer the code will look like:

```
a, b, c := s[0], s[1], s[2]
```